# Is 均等 a noun or adjective?

Tags: grammar, parsing

野菜をよく洗って、均等に切って、オーブンで焼きます。Is 均等 working here as a noun or adjective?

Answer (score 7):

均等【きんとう】 has both noun and *-na* adjective uses.  In this particular context, we could interpret this term either way.

As a noun:

> ...均等【きんとう】　　　　に　切【き】って、
>     ...equal parts `[IN]` cut, →
>     ... cut in equal parts,

As an adjective (with the に acting adverbially):

> ...均等【きんとう】　に　 切【き】って、
>     ...equal`[ly]` cut, →
>     ... cut equally / uniformly,

The ultimate meaning is the same whichever way we choose to parse this.